# ingresar datos Scanner a constructor

Tags: java, constructor, scanner

alguien que me explique por favor,como puedo invocar en la clase principal a las demas clases usando constructor con los datos que introduzco por teclado mediante Scanner,gracias.

CODIGO:

```
import java.util.*;
class Principal{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Principal pr=new Principal();


    }

               String titulo, autor, editorial;

               int nPaginas,anio;

               public Principal(String titulo,String autor,int nPagina){
                   this.titulo=titulo;
                   this.autor=autor;
                   this.nPaginas=nPaginas;

                              Scanner e=new Scanner(System.in);

                              System.out.println("Digite titulo del libro: ");

                              titulo=e.nextLine();

                              System.out.println("Digite autor del libro: ");

                              autor=e.nextLine();

                              System.out.println("Digite numero de paginas del libro: ");

                              nPaginas=e.nextInt();

               }

       public Principal(String editorial, int anio)

       {

           this.editorial=editorial;

           this.anio=anio;

       }

               public Principal (String msg)

               {

                              System.out.println(msg);

               }

               private void Datos1()

               {

                              System.out.println("Titulo del libro: "+ titulo);

                              System.out.println("Autor: "+ autor);

                              System.out.println("Numero de paginas: "+ nPaginas);

               }

               public void getDAtos1()

               {

                              Datos1();

               }

               public void Datos2()

               {

                              System.out.println("Editorial: " + editorial);

                              System.out.println("Año de publicacion: " + anio);

               }

}
class Docente{

   public String nombre="jorge";

   public String apellido="Peñate";

   public String materia="ciencias";

   public Docente(String msg){

       System.out.println("--------------------------------------");

       System.out.println(msg);

       System.out.println("--------------------------------------");

   }

private void nCompleto(){

    System.out.println(nombre+" "+apellido);

}   

private void getMateria(){

    System.out.println(materia);

}

public void getData(){

    nCompleto();

    getMateria();

}

}



class Alumno{

   public String carrera;

   public String materia;

   String nombre="Marcos";

   String carnet="22222";

   int edad=25;

   public Alumno(){

       System.out.println("Datos del Alumno");

       System.out.println("--------------------------------------");

   }

   public Alumno(String carrera, String materia){

       this.carrera=carrera;

       this.materia=materia;

   }

   public void getDatos(){

       System.out.println(this.nombre);

       System.out.println(this.carnet);

       System.out.println(this.edad);

   }

}
```

Comment: Puedes explicar mejor el problema.

Comment: segun instrucciones de la tarea,en la clase principal tengo que invocar las demas clase mediante el uso del metodo constructor,pero no entiendo como ya que algunas clases poseen Scanner system.in y eso me confunde

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al ver tu código por primera vez ha sido una tortura para mí. Cómo es posible que tu profesor te permita programar de esa manera? todo junto en una misma clase?... Me he tomado el tiempo de re-hacer tu ejercicio y comentar paso por paso para que logres entenderlo a la perfección y comiences a programar como lo hacen los profesionales.

1. Debes tener **cada objeto en su propia clase** (un .java separado), es decir, Alumno en una clase, Docente en otra y Libro en otra. De igual manera, otra clase con el método main.
2. Es siempre recomendable hacer uso del **Encapsulamiento** en Java.
   La encapsulación es uno de los principios fundamentales en la
   programación orientada a objetos (OOP), por lo que implementar
   **getter** y **setter** es una de las formas de aplicar la encapsulación en el código del programa. Con los getters obtendrás
   el valor de las variables que tenga la clase y con los setters
   modificarás su valor. Todo esto también te ayuda a tener un código
   más limpio, reducido y con menos probabilidades de cometer errores.
3. Luego de que veas mi código y lo entiendas, solo resta utilizar `Scanner` para pedir datos y guardarlos en las variables de las clases. Estoy seguro que podrás hacer esto sin mi ayuda.

Aquí te dejo todo el código necesario para tu ejercicio (y arreglado).

**Clase Alumno:**

```
public class Alumno {

    // Variables
    private String carrera;

    private String materia;

    private String nombre;

    private String carnet;

    private int edad = 25;

    // Constructor vacío para permitir que esta clase sea instanciada
    public Alumno() {
    }

    // Getters
    public String getCarrera() {
        return carrera;
    }

    public String getMateria() {
        return materia;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public String getCarnet() {
        return carnet;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    // Setters
    public void setCarrera(String carrera) {
        this.carrera = carrera;
    }

    public void setMateria(String materia) {
        this.materia = materia;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public void setCarnet(String carnet) {
        this.carnet = carnet;
    }

    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Alumno [carrera=" + carrera + ", materia=" + materia + ", nombre=" + nombre + ", carnet=" + carnet
                + ", edad=" + edad + "]";
    }
}
```

**Clase Docente:**

```
public class Docente {

    // Variables
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;
    private String materia;

    // Constructor vacío para permitir que esta clase sea instanciada
    public Docente() {
    }

    // Getters
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public String getApellido() {
        return apellido;
    }

    public String getMateria() {
        return materia;
    }

    // Setters
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public void setApellido(String apellido) {
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }

    public void setMateria(String materia) {
        this.materia = materia;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Docente [nombre=" + nombre + ", apellido=" + apellido + ", materia=" + materia + "]";
    }
}
```

**Clase Libro:**

```
public class Libro {

    // Variables
    private String titulo;
    private String autor;
    private String editorial;
    private int nPaginas;
    private int anio;

    // Constructor vacío para permitir que esta clase sea instanciada
    public Libro() {
    }

    // Getters
    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }

    public String getAutor() {
        return autor;
    }

    public String getEditorial() {
        return editorial;
    }

    public int getnPaginas() {
        return nPaginas;
    }

    public int getAnio() {
        return anio;
    }

    // Setters
    public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }

    public void setAutor(String autor) {
        this.autor = autor;
    }

    public void setEditorial(String editorial) {
        this.editorial = editorial;
    }

    public void setnPaginas(int nPaginas) {
        this.nPaginas = nPaginas;
    }

    public void setAnio(int anio) {
        this.anio = anio;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Libro [titulo=" + titulo + ", autor=" + autor + ", editorial=" + editorial + ", nPaginas=" + nPaginas
                + ", anio=" + anio + "]";
    }
}
```

**Clase Ejercicio (con el método main):**

```
public class Ejercicio {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /**
         * Instancias de cada clase.
         * Modificaremos el valor de sus variables con los SETTERS.
         */
        Libro libro = new Libro();
        libro.setTitulo("Los cuentos de pepito");
        libro.setAutor("Ramon Orlando");
        libro.setEditorial("Disney");
        libro.setAnio(2009);

        Docente docente = new Docente();
        docente.setNombre("Jose");
        docente.setApellido("Perez");
        docente.setMateria("Informática");

        Alumno alumno = new Alumno();
        alumno.setNombre("Manuel Castillo");
        alumno.setMateria("Informática");
        alumno.setCarrera("Ing. Sistemas");
        alumno.setCarnet("Tipo A");
        alumno.setEdad(26);

        /**
         * Imprimir en consola cada objeto.
         * Haremos uso del método toString() que tiene cada clase.
         * Puedes modificar este método en cada clase para que tenga la apariencia que desees.
         */
        System.out.println(libro.toString()); 
        System.out.println(docente.toString()); 
        System.out.println(alumno.toString()); 

        /**
         * Obtener un dato en específico de cada clase e imprimirlo
         */
        System.out.print("\n"); // Salto de línea 
        System.out.println("Título del libro: " + libro.getTitulo()); 
        System.out.println("Nombre del docente: " + docente.getNombre() + " " + docente.getApellido()); 
        System.out.println("Nombre del alumno: " + alumno.getNombre()); 
    }
}
```

Si sigues teniendo dudas sobre cómo y dónde pedir datos con Scanner y cómo guardarlos (espero que lo hayas resuelto por tu cuenta, aunque sea mentalmente), aquí te dejo un ejemplo (el siguiente código va dentro de la clase Ejercicio, en el método main):

```
// Pedir dato (en este caso un nuevo nombre para el alumno)
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Ingrese el nuevo nombre del alumno: ");
String nuevoNombre = sc.nextLine();
sc.close(); // Cerrar el Scanner

// Guardar el dato en la clase Alumno utilizando el SETTER
alumno.setNombre(nuevoNombre);
```

Espero haberte ayudado, saludos!.

Comment: Gracias por la explicacion,y pues esa clase desordenada no la cree yo sino que la ha hizo la profesora,ami tambien me ha causado estres tratar de entender el codigo.

Comment: Me alegra haberte ayudado amigo. Al inicio puede ser confuso pero, ya te acostumbraras. Recuerda seleccionar mi respuesta como la elegida. Saludos